# Faster Upload Speeds with AWS EC2 Instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, file-upload

I've got a t2.medium instance with an EBS volume and EFS in the U.S. West (Oregon) availability region.

Users (often out of California) can upload image files using a javascript file uploader, but no matter how fast the user's connection is, they can't seem to upload any faster than ~500kb/s.

For example, if a user speed-tests their upload rate at 5mb/s, and then uploads a 5MB image file, it will still take nearly 11 seconds to complete.

I get similar results when using FTP to upload files.

My initial thought was that I should change my instance to something with better Network Performance — but since I'm uploading directly to the EFS and not an amazon bucket or something else, I wasn't sure networking was my problem.

How can I achieve faster upload rates? Is this a limitation of my instance?

Answer (score 5):

I would definitely experiment with different instance types as the instance family and size is directly correlated with the network performance.  The `t2` family of instances has one of the lowest network throughputs.

Here are two resources to help you figure out what to expect for network throughput for the various instance types:

- [Cloudonaut EC2 Network Performance Cheat Sheet](https://cloudonaut.io/ec2-network-performance-cheat-sheet/)
- [Amazon EC2 Instance Type documentation](https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/instance-types/)

The `t3` family is the latest gen of low cost and burstable `t` instances which include enhanced networking with a much improved burstable network rate of up to 5 Gbps.  This may work for you if your uploads are infrequent.  At a minimum, you could switch to the `t3` family to improve your network performance without changing your cost much at all.

Side note: If you are using an older AMI, you may not be able to directly use your AMI from your t2 instance as you will need a modern version of an OS that supports the enhanced networking.

Comment: you may even lower your costs as `t3` instances are cheaper than `t2` instances to motivate users to move away from the older gens/hardware